# error messages not displaying in custom form template in drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I did this using below function in template.php

```
function mytheme_theme() {
  return array(
    'nsa_create_form' => array(
       'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
       'template' => 'nsa-create',
       ),
   );
}
```

And added nsa-create.tpl.php with the below lines of code

```
<?php if ($show_messages && $messages): print $messages; endif; ?>

<?= drupal_render($form['start_date']) ?>
<?= drupal_render($form['end_date']) ?>
<?= drupal_render($form['confirm_dates']) ?>
<?= drupal_render($form['name']) ?>
<?= drupal_render($form['emp_id']) ?>
<?= drupal_render($form['client']) ?>
<?= drupal_render($form['designation']) ?>
<?= drupal_render($form['manager']) ?>
<?= drupal_render($form['competency']) ?>
<?= drupal_render($form['wrapper_nsa']) ?>
<?= drupal_render($form['submit']) ?>
```

its rendered properly but error/validation messages are not displayed and no red border for invalid fields.

Comment: IIRC, the error messages of forms use the 'standard' Drupal message channel, i.e. they get injected into the page template, _not into the form template._ As for the red borders on invalid fields, these should come as `class="error"` on the field element wrappers - you should check if your rendering logic includes the wrapping divs (and that your CSS properly reacts to the error class).

Answer (score 1):

does your page.tpl.php have

```
<?php print $messages; ?>
```